# VS Code: how to permanently stick Command Palette to the UI

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not entirely happy pressing ctrl+shift+p every thirty seconds in order to put in a simple command. How can I make the command palette stay on the screen all the time?

Comment: I think a previous version of VS Code had the command palette open continuously. I preferred it like that.

Answer (score 13):

You can make the command palette always visible by right clicking on top of the editor (where the filename is) and selecting "Command Center".

Menu for the command palette:
[image: Menu for the command palette]

Comment: Oh, thanks. This apparently was added this July, I completely missed this tidbit. Need to make a point of reading patch notes carefully.

Comment: Pretty much useless because the default function is "search files" and you have to click "Show and Run Commands" which is the same effort as clicking "View" -> "Command Palette".

Comment: I've unchecked "Launch Command Center" by right clicking on the command center at the top bar of the vscode Window and no it's disappeared, how do I get it back?

Comment: You can right click on the arrows where the command center was and the option to make it visible is there.

Comment: Linux user here, this dropdown option is missing entirely for me. I also cannot find any option within the `View` menu or in the preferences. Is there any way to have the palette fixed in Linux? Distribution is Kubuntu 23.10.