# How Can I Remove the Visual Studio Code Top Bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Please see this image please.]

How to hide the whole top bar?

I cannot find online how to hide/show it.

Comment: right click on the top bar and uncheck the **Command Center**, and look in the menu **View** > **Appearrance** for Full mode and Zen mode

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53890179/11107541

Answer (score 11):

The top bar is called the [Command Center](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_command-center).

To hide it:

1. Open VS Code settings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> for MacOS)
2. Search for "Window: Command Center" and turn the setting off

[image: vs code settings]

Answer (score 4):

You can also right click on the Command Center to hide it.
[image]