# How to remove new search-bar from window title in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

- VSCode version: 1.81.0
- macOS Version: Ventura 13.2.1
- Theme used: Material Theme

This used to be just text without the arrow icons; How can I get the old visuals and behavior back? I will never click on this to activate the same window as with CMD+P

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53890179/11107541

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Remove the Visual Studio Code Top Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74967999/how-can-i-remove-the-visual-studio-code-top-bar)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Right click on the search bar and disable "Command Center". That will return the old view.

Alternatively, go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Window and disable Command Center there. The key is `window.commandCenter` if you need it for a settings.json file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I love the internet <3 – Would you mind to share where you got that information from? I'd like to learn how to find stuff like this myself, because believe it or not– I tried beforehand. I think the main issue is that I didn't know its called "Command Center"

Comment: I'd love to give you a more helpful answer there (usually I do research and add sources) but I honestly just right-clicked the top bar and tried what was there, then looked in the settings for the corresponding one. I'll leave my opinion on that genius name out of here though (Calling a search bar and forwards-backwards buttons a "Command Center" is... original).

Comment: "original" to say the least– thanks a lot again!